# For accessing data offline, better to use Room library or HTTP cache-control?

Tags: android, caching, android-room, cache-control

I looked into solving the problem of accessing data offline in Android and came across Room library and HTTP cache-control. I already have all of the Retrofit / OkHttp responses done in my app. Which is better to implement when there is no Internet connection?

Comment: My suggestion is Room, easy to using and very stable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It greatly depends on the requirements of your app.

**Room** allows you to save and *organise* the data. Specific queries and extraction of distinct objects is very powerful if needed. Besides that you can be sure the data won't be deleted, when the device needs storage and clears the cache folders. One problem however is data integrity, which would require some sort of synchroniser between your app and the backend server. I would advise you to use Room if you do any sort of data manipulation and/or want to offer certain and reliable offline user experience.

**HTTP CACHE** is simpler and a quite straightforward solution. You only need to add a interceptor to your OkHttp client and you are ready to go. This would be the solution if you app's main purpose is simply displaying data.

Comment: Is there any downside to doing OkHttp caching?  Like when would the cache be lost.